# Apache vhosts help needed

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration

I am trying to configure vhosts for my local development machine, I did it before, but somehow, I am having problems now.

I am trying to have 2 vhosts

```
http://tickle -> D:\Projects\LearnZendTest\public
http://localhost -> D:\Websites
```

My vhosts config looks like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/Projects/LearnZendTest/public"
    ServerName learnzendtest
    <Directory "D:/Projects/LearnZendTest/public">
        AllowOverride All
        Options All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/Websites"
    ServerName localhost
    <Directory "D:/Websites">
        AllowOverride All
        Options All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I notice apache only takes into consideration the 1st entry. If I have the entry for localhost 1st, even when I goto http://tickle, I will get to `D:\Websites`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see a ServerName or ServerAlias with value `tickle`. With these settings, I expect `D:/Projects/LearnZendTest/public` to be served.

Above your `<VirtualHost>` blocks, you should have the following as well:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

This enables name-based virtual hosting (multiple VirtualHost with the same IP, distinguished by ServerName or ServerAlias.
if you want Apache to server `D:/Websites/` for `http://tickle/`, you should modify `ServerName localhost` to `ServerName tickle` or add `ServerAlias tickle` (below ServerName will be fine). Finally, a change in the hosts file is necessary for your browser mapping `http://tickle/` to `127.0.0.1`. Edit `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` with notepad (Administrator permissions is required). Add:

```
127.0.0.1 tickle
```

Links:

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html
- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost

Comment: thanks, tickle was a typo, I just didn't put in the the code snipplet. But the main part I was missing was `NameVirtualHost *:80`